# Hola, como terminar proceso cara cierto tiempo

Tags: c#

Como terminar proceso cada cierto tiempo:

```
Process process4 = new Process(); // mi codigo

process4.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/C taskkill /im Exmple.exe",
};
```

¿Como hacer para terminarlo después de 15 segundos por ejemplo?

Comment: Windows form???

Comment: Puedes poner ese código en un `while` y averiguar el tiempo que pasó restando 2 `DateTime` o con `Stopwatch`. O puedes poner el código en un método asíncrono y esperar un `Task.Delay(tiempo)`.

Comment: cualquier proceso o uno creado desde C#?

Comment: ¿Me puedes poner un ejemplo de como quedaria? Gracias.

Comment: culquier proceso y si es un tiempo RANDOM entre 2 y 5 minutos o algo a si mejor